# Synthetic Differential Topology

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, synthetic-differential-geometry

I have read the introduction to [this work](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325555340_Synthetic_differential_topology), which explains the foundations of Synthetic Differential Topology (an extension of Synthetic Differential Geometry) and I was wondering, since the book is - I think - still to appear, whether there are any other descriptions/introductions to the subject, or also articles on it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The book has [appeard](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/synthetic-differential-topology/446AD9AE704BD756D03769528DF668A0).